# cypher query to traverse a graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cql

I am using [last.fm](http://blog.bruggen.com/2013/10/same-csv-files-different-neo4j-database.html) dataset and imported it in neo4j 2.0.1. Now i want to traverse the graph so that I can get similar result which, I am getting by executing following **MySQL query**:

```
SELECT * from music.logs, music.features, music.nodespart2
WHERE logs.song="1000001" 
    AND logs.song=features.scrobble 
    AND fetures.mbid=nodespart2.name;
```

In **neo4j** I want to execute similar query,
starting from a particular `index lets say 1000001->logs->features`...
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you share dataset sample or any graph diagram ?

Comment: Graph is http://imgur.com/dgvzHFA

Comment: Graph is http://imgur.com/dgvzHFA and structure of tables used for above MySQL query is http://imgur.com/iwi2fon. There are 9 csv files which have been used to import nodes and relationships in neo4j. In second figure which i have shared, FEATURES & LOGS are two types of relationships between nodes. The value in "TYPE" column of these two tables is FEATURES & LOGS respectively i.e. the entry is same in all the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not pretty sure about the graph model yet and what propertiess are you storing in the nodes and on relationship. But from the links you shared I think below query should work..

```
 MATCH (a)-[:LOGS]->(b)-[:FEATURES]->(c) where a.type="listener" 
 and b.type="scrobble"
 and c.type="track" and b.name = "100001" return *
```

This will give all `listeners` and `tracks` related to a particular `scrobble` with name `1000001`

**EDIT after comment**

```
 MATCH (b)-[:FEATURES]->(c) where b.type="scrobble" and c.type="track" 
 and b.name = "100001" return c.title
```

I would recommend to reimport your dataset with `Labels`. More info on labels: [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/graphdb-neo4j-labels.html). It will save the effort of checking type again and again and will enable you to incorporate it in the match pattern itself; also its more efficient.

**EDIT** after labels were added

Query1:

```
MATCH (a:listener)-[:LOGS]->(b:scrobble)-[:FEATURES]->(c:track) 
where b.name = "100001" return *
```

Query2:

```
MATCH (b:scrobble)-[:FEATURES]->(c:track) where b.name = "100001" return c.title
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I tried to execute that query but it returned 0 rows. Well let me again state my purpose? I want to get the title of that track related to a particular scrobble 100001. Let me explain you in a diagramatic way that might help it. The flow of my requirement is shown here http://imgur.com/pxhtV6W where  I want to get the title for a particular scrobble. The screenshots that might help you for geting to know the relationships are at http://imgur.com/LtHLTra,D4Qvasp and http://imgur.com/LtHLTra,D4Qvasp#1.

Comment: No, its is still nt working. Can you tell me,what should be the query to see one node from graph as output. I want to get node="100001".

Comment: if the node has label ABC and an attribute name = "10001" then you do simple MATCH (a:ABC) where a.name = "10001" return a

is 100001 node id or the name of the scrobble???

Comment: try edit again.. your database doesnt have labels instead it is using type... i just noticed in your screenshot..

Comment: I re-imported the csv files into neo4j with labels. Now you can see the updated screenshot http://imgur.com/AephVWw